# Reading files in a folder one by one in C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a simple question, but that it's driving me crazy.
I have a folder with a lot of `JSON` files inside, I need just to open those files one by one and do things.
So, I need to open the first one, read it and do something then go to the second one etc. until the last.

Here the code I tried, searching on web:

```
string folderpath = @"C:\Users\rfo\Desktop\MM\VM DB\nv - master\nvd";
            var fixedfolderpath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(folderpath);
            string [] filesnumber = Directory.GetFiles(fixedfolderpath, "*.json");
            foreach (string filename in filesnumber)
            {
                var jsonFull = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);
```

But I keep gettin error `DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path on the browser`.
I'm using `asp.net CORE 3` and visual studio 2019.

Comment: What does `fixedfolderpath` contains?

Comment: The AppPool probably has no access to the users folder. And use Server.MapPath.

Comment: could be an access rights issue. move the folder to shared drive have to access to asp.net user

Comment: please print output of fixedfolderpath, and do an if Directory.Exist(fixedfolderpath) before Directory.GetFiles

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen fixedfolderpath contains a lot of JSON files.

Comment: @VDWWD How I do it?

Comment: @KrishnaMohanVarma For example in a folder under the solution pattern?

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti Perdonami non ho capito

Comment: @RobNone preferably the folder should be outside solution path

Comment: In IIS you're supposed to access folders under the application root folder; so, create a folder under your IIS site and put your files in there, as you're not supposed to access the desktop folder anyways

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the files from your desktop, you could use this instead:

```
string path = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), 
    @"MM\VM DB\nv - master\nvd");
```

But you probably got access right problems

Comment: _"If you want to get the files from your desktop"_ - no, you don't want that in an ASP.NET application which will presumably run in IIS. Your Application Pool user doesn't have a desktop folder loaded by default.

Comment: Not working, I guess i still have rights problems. If I would move it under a solution folder?

Comment: That would be better

Answer (score 0):

1. As others suggest, it's better to move the files inside the solution. For example, you could copy those files into the project folder:

   ```
   ├───YourApp.csproj                      # your `*.csproj`
   ├───Controllers/
   ├───Models/
   ├───Views/
   ├───wwwroot/
   ├───MM/                                 # your target folder 
   │   └───VM/
   │       └───VM DB/
   │           └───nv - master/
   │               └───nvd/
   |                   └─── *.json
   ```
2. Apart from that, don't forget to **add a configuration** in your **`*.csproj`** file such that your json files will be copied automatically when you build/publish the app:

   ```xml
     <ItemGroup>
       <None Update="MM\**\*.*">
         <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
       </None>
     </ItemGroup>
   ```
3. Also, it seems that you're using the ASP.NET Core instead of ASP.NET. If that's the case, you could reference this folder by injecting an [`IWebHostEnvironment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment?view=aspnetcore-3.0) so that you invoke `webHostEnv.ContentRootPath` to get root directory (i.e., the project file direction in source code, and the directory of YourAssembly.dll when published).

   For example, you could inject an `IWebHostEnviroment` instance in the controller:

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
       public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
       {
           this._env = env;
       }
       public IActionResult Privacy()
       {
           var dir = Path.Combine( this._env.ContentRootPath, @"MM\VM\VM DB\nv - master\nvd");
           string[] filesnumber = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.json");
           foreach (string filename in filesnumber)
           {
               var jsonFull = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);
               ...
           }
           return Ok("hello,world");
        }
   }
   ```
4. Finally, in case you don't like dependency injection, or cannot use dependency injection, you could use a path relative to current assembly as below:

   ```cs
    var assemDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    var dir = Path.Combine(assemDir, @"MM\VM\VM DB\nv - master\nvd");
    string[] filesnumber = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.json");
   ```

   Be careful this is not the safest way. It is suggested that we should use the DI approach (`IWebHostEnviroment`) if possible.